# How to check which class type the object is when it inherits from a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

Lets say I have 3 different classes: Equipment, Weapon and Tools. Weapon and Tools inherits Equipment. I created a Weapon or Tool object and added it to a Equipment array. When I retrieve the object, how do I write my "IF" statement to check if this object is a Weapon or Tool?

Thanks

Comment: `polymorphism` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic_cast as follows:

```
Equipment *pMyObj = ... //got it somewhere

Weapon *pWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon *>(pMyObj);

if( pWeapon != NULL ){ 
 //you have weapon 
}
```

Comment: One handy trick is to declare the variable inside the if condition: `if (Weapon *pWeapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(pMyObj)) { /* you have a weapon */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about RTTI ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information#C.2B.2B_Example)) however it might be better if you kept a 'type' enum in your Equipment base class, then just check against that to find out what the derived type is.  Then you can just `dynamic_cast` the Equipment object to the correct derived type.

Answer (score 0):

if (dynamic_cast< Weapon* >(Equipment_ptr) != NULL) // then Weapon

Answer (score 0):

Believe typeid is another option ..

```
if (typeid(thing)==typeid(otherthing)){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat mixed feeling about dynamic_cast, though.

While it will work, it might not be the best choice if the number of choices can grow. In such cases, i would prefer a "kind"-enumeration, and a virtual GetKind() method. This allows a nice switch() statement on the enum, and most compilers should even be able to warn you if you forgot to list one of the enum values.

Since you already know what class you're dealing with in the case: sections, you don't need to dynamic_cast anymore, so you don't need to do the same check twice.

Of course, DO try to keep your switch() or if-else-cascades limited; take a look at why you need to check for the class, and spend a minute or two to consider putting the code into a virtual method instead. I'm not saying to never test for the class type, but I think one should at least make it a concious decision :-)